# filtering a dataframe on values in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame :-

[image]

I want to filter where ever there is 11 in `claim_status`

and for the `claim_ststaus_reason` for aa1.

I am trying to the below code but it simply giving me all the rows

```
my_list = 'aa1'

df[df['claim_status_reason'].str.contains( "|".join(my_list), regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Expected output:-

```
1.) where there is 11 in claim_ststus 
2.) where there is aa1 in the claim_status_reason
```

Comment: do you have the  dataFrame in text form, it can be quickly tested pls.

Comment: yes i do have how do i can share

Comment: Please do that, However worth trying like  something `df.apply(lambda col: col.str[0])`

Comment: `df.mask(lambda x: 11 in x['claim_status_reason'])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` to obtain your desired filter like:

```
df[(df['claim_staus'].apply(lambda x: 11 in x)) & (df['claim_status_reason'].apply(lambda x: 'a1' in x))]
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use string operations on lists within series. You can use list comprehensions instead. Your data structure choice is anti-Pandas because you should try to avoid putting lists in series in the first place. These operations are not vectorisable.

```
mask1 = np.array([11 in x for x in df['claim_staus']])
mask2 = np.array(['aa1' in x for x in df['claim_status_reason']])

df = df[mask1 & mask2]
```

Comment: Good One @jpp, i read today lists are not good within pandas dataFrame!

Comment: @jpp is this method better than applying element-wise?

Comment: This is faster (or at worst comparable) to `apply` + `lambda` (which under the hood is just another Python-level loop).

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df['claim_staus'].tolist()).eq('aa1').any()`

Comment: @W-B, I wouldn't recommend this with jagged list lengths. You could end up with a huge number of `NaN` values (i.e. memory inefficient). Moreover, it's only superficially vectorised, since the expensive bit (testing strings) cannot be vectorised with `object` dtype.